# Changing second color of AnnArbor beamer theme?

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm currently working on a presentation using the beamer layout of AnnArbor theme, but changed its color to Seahorse by saying

```
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
```

It now looks like this:
[image: Current coloring]

I would like to change the yellow part into another color. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this answer from TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208563/49683), line 4 of the following should fit for you:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue,bg=orange}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Agenda}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please comment otherwise! :)